# how to convert date format for ASP.Net Web API with signalR?

Tags: signalr, asp.net-web-api

I have implemented asp.net web api along with signalr in order to push data to the client.

The payload consists of pushing a DateTime value to the browser thru signalR in Asp.Net Web API.

The problem is when the data is recievied on browser I am getting date in iso format 
i.e.  2012-12-04T19:30:18 but i want data in microsoftdate format i.e "\date(...)"

For this to work I tried following in the application_start event in global.asax of asp.net web api:

```
    var json =config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        json.SerializerSettings.DateFormatHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat;
```

but still getting date as "2012-12-04T19:30:18".

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with SignalR 1.0, you can register your own JsonNetSerializer on app start with custom settings like so:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class Global : HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
            settings.DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat;
            var serializer = new JsonNetSerializer(settings);

            GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IJsonSerializer), () => serializer);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks halter..thats exaclty I wanted. the above implemenation is working.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't entirely follow the issue you're running into but I'm assuming you're trying to pass the current DateTime down from the server to the client and read it?

If so you can send it/parse via the following (no need for any serialization changes):
[SignalR datetime format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13365294/signalr-datetime-format/13366276)

This is the JavaScript way to read the DateTIme.